# Hydrant Renumbering in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5

[image]I am working on a hydrant renumbering project. We have over 1,500 hydrants and the land base is filled up sporadically as new subdivisions are built. However this cause our numbers to be all over the place. We service a number of towns within the county. We have decided that since we are still small enough we will be able to renumber the hydrants by town. So we would start with a letter in front of the hydrant number corresponding to the town the hydrant is in and starting from 1 and numbering up. I clipped out the hydrants based on town but was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on the best tools to use in ArcGIS 10.5 to complete the process. I would like the hydrants to be numbered somewhat uniformly geographically.

Comment: A few questions to clarify: What type of pattern are you looking for? Can you upload a screenshot/ sketched sample area where you've manually named the hydrants, and we can assist you with the automation process? Do the hydrants have to be in order by street?

Comment: ArcGIS has a Sort Tool with a Spatial Sort option.

Comment: The pattern we are looking for ideally is nearest neighbor. We would like the  hydrant points numbered in succession according to their nearest neighbor, in a north to south direction.

Comment: Also we have created a new field for those numbers to be added to. These numbers would need to start at 1 and go on from there.